# click button (CSS) using JS script

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, button, effects

Im making a simon says game,
i use 4 colored buttons that works perfectly.
the process is simple- the program present the user with the colors.
the repeat the sequence by clicking the buttons.

I wish to let the program activate the button the same way a user would, with the appropriate activate effect.

```
.but:active{ // <-- how do i initiate this with js?
        box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
        transform: translateY(4px);
```

Comment: You could use a class instead of `:active`.

Answer (score 2):

You mean

```
document.querySelector(".but").click()
```

or

```
const buts = document.querySelectorAll(".but");
const cnt = 0;
setInterval(function() { 
  if (cnt>= 0) cnt = 0; 
  but[cnt].click();
  cnt++;
},2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let but = document.querySelector('.but');

but.addEventListener('click', () => {
   but.classList.add('active');

   let activeStatus = document.querySelector('.active');
   activeStatus.style = `
   box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
   transform: translateY(4px);
  `;
});
```

Comment: this is not what OP asked. They want to programmatically click the button